# Is there a way to leave notes on/annotate a PDF file in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

Ok, so I have a web-application that I'm making in ReactJS. Currently, users are able to upload pdfs using the 'React-File-picker' package and then view them by clicking a button.

If they want to leave notes on the pdf file they're viewing, they have to do it in a textbox at the bottom of the file viewer which seems intrusive and annoying (see screenshot 1). I've received a lot of requests to allow the user to click on the document itself and leave a note there sort of like how Adobe Arobat does (see screenshot 2).

Any recommendations on how I should approach this because I'm pretty lost currently.

Thanks

[image]

The textbox that's currently there ^^^

[image]

This is how I want to be able to do it ^^^

Comment: I think what you'd likely end up doing is using canvas, and rendering the PDF on it. That way you can listen for clicks and know what [x,y] coordinates they clicked on.

Comment: Any tips on where to look for that? I tried that & didn't have much luck in terms of displaying the pdf on the canvas

Comment: I am not sure if you also consider using paid options, but [this solution](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/pdfviewer/text-markup-annotation/#text-markup-annotation) seems to offer what you are looking for.